# generics : getting parameterizedtype classname from a static method?

Tags: java

I have a simple static method :

```
public static <U> U findStuff(String id) {
    // how can i get the class of type U here ?
    Class classObject = ....;

    return classObject.newInstance();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyEntity entity = MyClass.<MyEntity>findStuff("abc");
}
```

I wonder how i can get the class object from the U ?

Currently i have to pass the class around because i dont know the way yet.. so, now im using something like this  :

```
public static <U> U findStuff(Class<U> classObject, String id) {
    return classObject.newInstance();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyEntity entity = MyClass.findStuff(MyEntity.class, "abc");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does

```
Class<?> classObject = object.getClass();
```

do enough for you? It's not clear what you need `em.find` to do.

EDIT: Okay, with the edit, you're running into the problem of *type erasure*. Basically, you need to pass in the class you're interested in, as you're already doing. See the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information. It's an unfortunate corollary of the way that Java generics are implemented :(

Comment: Jon Skeet: Sorry for the post that doesnt describe my problem. I've updated my post again. Thank you !

Comment: Jon Skeet: Ah, i dont really understand yet, but will take a look into it. I was thinking something like what is available for parameterized class, like doing the getClass().getGenericSuperClass().getActualTypeArguments. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To get the class of the object, use `object.getClass();`

By the way, this is a common way to do it that is not related to **Generics**

Comment: MByD: Sorry, my bad earlier post. I've updated my post again. Thank you !

Comment: @Albert Kam - I think you can't do it as you describe, but the guy below will probably give you a certain answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// because object extends java.lang.Object
Class<?> classObject = object.getClass();
```

Comment: MarvinLabs: Sorry, wrong example in my previous post. I've updated my post again. Thank you !